# How to show images in MVC Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, image, model-view-controller

I have few images in folder in View section of the application. I want to show those images in my view form but I could not show these images. There might be something wrong with the url.

this is my view form

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`enter code here`
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Ceylon Brokers</title>
        @section styles{
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="@Href("~/css/styles.css")" />
}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="background">
            <div id="footer"><img alt="social_links" usemap="#social" src=@Url.Content("~/images/footer.png")>
            <map id="social" name="social">
            <area shape="circle" coords="79,122.5,35" href="https://www.facebook.com/ceylonbrokers?fref=ts" alt="social_links"/>
            <area shape="circle" coords="160,123,34.5" href="" alt="social_links"/>
            <area shape="circle" coords="245,122.5,35" href="http://www.linkedin.com" alt="social_links"/>
            </map>
            </div>
            <div id="whyusbg"><img src="~/images/whyusbg.png"></div>

            <div id="header"><img alt="page_titles" usemap="#pages" src="../images/header.png">
            <map id="pages" name="pages">
            <area shape="rect" coords="430,90,520,120" href="index.html" alt="page_titles"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="540,90,690,120" href="about.html" alt="page_titles"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="720,90,880,120" href="" alt="page_titles"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="910,90,1110,120" href="" alt="page_titles"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="1140,90,1340,120" href="" alt="page_titles"/>
            <area shape="rect" coords="1370,90,1550,120" href="" alt="page_titles"/>
            </map>
            </div>
        </div>
 </body>
 </htm
```

The following images are unavailable.

```
http://localhost:50242/images/whyusbg.png 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:50242/images/footer.png 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost:50242/images/header.png 404 (Not Found)
```

How could I link my image files to the form?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In the #footer div you use Url.Content() to load an image, but later for example in #whyusbg div you use src="~/images/whyusbg.png". Try using Url.Content() method in each place where you load image.

Comment: @AndrewB Actually none of those methods work. I just want to show that I have used every method that I know to get the result but still doesn't work

Comment: Can you tell me the path to the images folder in your project relatively to project root folder then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images shouldn't really be in the `View` folder of the application. Typically you would have a `Content` folder on the root of the MVC site and then I personally put my `images` folder in there. 
Then, to access any image you would say:

```
@Url.Content("~/content/images/my-image.jpg")
```

If you want the images folder on the root of the site, just put `images` on the same folder level as the current `view` folder and access like:

```
@Url.Content("~/images/my-image.jpg")
```